# Validation of [Required] attribute failing in xUnit test with Entity Framework Core

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, data-annotations, xunit.net

In this class library (targeting .NET Standard 2.0 and .NET Framework 4.6.1), I am doing data validation at the data context level, as these classes may be used by non-web applications, so I'm following the example from https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/issues/9662 in a static helper class:

```
internal static ICollection<ValidationResult> ValidateChanges(DbContext context)
{
    var modifiedEntries = context.ChangeTracker.Entries()
                                 .Where(x => x.State == EntityState.Added || 
                                             x.State == EntityState.Modified);
    List<ValidationResult> validationResults = new List<ValidationResult>();

    foreach (var entry in modifiedEntries)
    {
        var validationContext = new ValidationContext(entry);
        Validator.TryValidateObject(entry, validationContext, validationResults, true);
    }

    return validationResults;
}
```

My POCO (simplified):

```
public class Person
{
    [Required]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    // other properties
}
```

My unit test (simplified):

```
[Fact]
public void TestDataValidation()
{
    IPersonService svc = _container.Resolve<IPersonService>();
    Person p = svc.Get(1);
    string origValue = p.FirstName;
    p.FirstName = string.Empty;

    try
    {
        Assert.Throws<ValidationException>(() => svc.Update(p, p.Id));
    }
    catch (Xunit.Sdk.XunitException) // ValidationException not thrown
    {
        // restore original value

        throw;
    }
}
```

The service class method:

```
    public virtual TEntity Update(TEntity entity, TKey key)
    {
        if (entity == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(entity));

        ((IDatabaseContext)Context).BeginTransaction();
        TEntity dbEntity = Get(key);
        Context.Entry(dbEntity).CurrentValues.SetValues(entity);
        ((IDatabaseContext)Context).Commit();
        return entity;
    }
```

The `Commit()` method:

```
public abstract class DatabaseContext<TContext> : DbContext, IDatabaseContext
    where TContext : DbContext
{
    public void Commit()
    {
        ICollection<ValidationResult> validationResults = DbContextHelper.ValidateChanges(this);
        if (validationResults.Count > 0)
        {
            foreach (ValidationResult validationResult in validationResults)
            {
                string message = string.Format("{0}: {1}", string.Join(", ", validationResult.MemberNames.ToArray()), validationResult.ErrorMessage);
                throw new ValidationException(message);
            }
        }
        base.Commit();
    }
}
```

When I execute the test, the validation complete fails. When I put a break point in the middle of the foreach loop of the validation method, this is what I see:

- `modifiedEntries` has one item (as expected)
- `entry.CurrentValues["FirstName"]` is an empty string (as expected)
- When you view it in the debugger watch list, `entry.CurrentValues.Properties[5]` shows `{Property: Person.FirstName (string) Required}` (seems right)
- `validationContext.Items` shows `Count = 0` (wait, what? shouldn't this be 1?)

Then when I reach the end of the validation method, `validationResults` is empty, even though there definitely should be something in there.

According to [Data annotations attributes not working in asp net core](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57807712/data-annotations-attributes-not-working-in-asp-net-core) you need `AddDataAnnotations()` on the ServiceCollection, but that's in ASP.NET MVC Core. Is there something similar I needed to do for my unit test application? Am I missing anything else?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like that

```
//Assert
foreach (var item in ValidateModel(itemToCreate))
{
    if(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(item.ErrorMessage)) throw new ValidationException(item.ErrorMessage); 
}

/////

private static IList<ValidationResult> ValidateModel(object model)
{
    var validationResults = new List<ValidationResult>();
    var ctx = new ValidationContext(model, null, null);
    Validator.TryValidateObject(model, ctx, validationResults, true);
    return validationResults;
}
```